# How to associate multiple values inside a hashtable - java

Tags: java, hashtable, phonebook

I am trying to implement a basic phonebook using a hashtable made from scratch i made but when adding a contact i will need to store atleast 2 informations, the name and number of each person.

The problem is when adding the info into the hashtable i can only do it like
x.insert(name) and x.insert(number) witch will result in 2 different keys and i cant find away to associate the two values within the hashtable. Is this even possible to do?

If needed i can provide the code.

PS: the hashtable i made has the methods: insert(y),remove(y),find(y),print()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a class that stores the name and number, and have your hashtable store these.

Comment: That is something i didnt consider, i will give ir a try. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as said by @hnefatl in a comment, create some class:

```
public class PhoneBookInfos {
    public String Name;
    public String Number;
}
```

and your hashtable/HashMap would be:

```
Map<Integer, PhoneBookInfos> myPhoneBook = new HashMap<Integer, PhoneBookInfos>();
```

updated after @hnefatl's comment

Comment: You shouldn't use `Map` as the type - use `Map<Integer, PhoneBookInfos>`. `Map` refers to the pre-generics version of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The insert function could check to see if the key exists, retrieve the object, and then add the missing field, and add that object back into the hashtable. Otherwise create the object with only the name or number, and add that into the hashtable.